# Other ways of executing #if condition from a string var in C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I am trying to execute the condition given in a string var "str".
I tried to place it inside a macro define, but it does not work.
Unlike, when the condition is directly defined like in the "CONDITION_DEF".

```
    #define CONDITION_STR str
    #define CONDITION_DEF defined A && defined B
    #define A 1
    #define B 1


    int main(){
        char *str = "defined A && defined B";
        #if CONDITION_STR
        printf("Condition from str: A and B are defined");
        #endif

        #if CONDITION_DEF
        printf("Condition from define: A and B are defined");
        #endif
     }
```

OUTPUT:

```
"Condition from define: A and B are defined"
```

The condition is placed in a string var so that I can be able to change it during runtime.
Is there other way to be able to execute #if condition from a string variable?
Thanks!

Comment: You won't be able to use #if because it's a preprocessor directive, you'll have to use a 'normal' if.

Comment: Oh okay, is my understanding correct, that if I changed the str to *str = "1 && 0";` then use 'normal' if instead, It can be evaluated like a normal if(1 && 0) would be?

Comment: I tried changing str to *str = "1 && 0" and use normal if instead, it runs but the if result is always true.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible as the preprocessing is done before the actual compilation of the C code. Preprocessor does not know anything about C and C variables.

Comment: Oh I see, so it means the COND_STR str can't get the value of the string str.